# Queue spaces in URL GET parameter

Tags: php, url, get

When I have URL like this

`site.com/index.php?name=JON%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SMIT`

and I print `$_GET['name']` variable in index.php file, result is `Jon Smit`.

That is, queue spaces between JON and SMIT, are replaced on one space. why this happened?

Answer (score 2):

HTML ignores extraneous whitespace, so no matter how many spaces you put in the name, when it is output in a browser, the browser will only show one space. You need to replace your spaces with `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) to ensure the browser displays them all.

Answer (score 1):

This should preserve the spaces:

```
print rawurldecode($_GET['name']);
```

This will print the extra spaces, however your browser may ignore the extra spaces.
[Documentation](https://www.php.net/urldecode)

Answer (score 1):

How the special chars (like the space) is encodet in the URL is defined, look also [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). You can URL encode via [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php) and the inverse of that is [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.urldecode.php)

About the ONE Space only: Look into the source of the Page (i.e. the HTML-Code), in Firefox e.g. via Ctrl+U, there will be many more spaces. BUT: The browser only displays one of them. If you want to preserve them in the output, you could use something like

```
echo '<pre>' . $_GET['name'] . '</pre>';
```

OR

```
echo str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $_GET['name']);
```